# Parallel-processing efficient_apriori code in Python

Tags: python, apriori

I have 12 millions of data from an eshop. I would like to compute association rules using efficient_apriori package. `The problem is that 12 millions observations are too many`, so the computation tooks too much time. Is there a way how to speed up the algorithm? I am thinking about some Parallel-processing or compile python code into C. I tried PYPY, but PYPY does not support pandas package. Thank you for any help or idea.

If you want to see my code:

```py
import pandas as pd

from efficient_apriori import apriori

orders = pd.read_csv("orders.csv", sep=";")

customer = orders.groupby("id_customer")["name"].agg(tuple).tolist()

itemsets, rules = apriori(
            customer, min_support=100/len(customer), min_confidence=0
        )
```

Comment: How long does it take for your 12M data?

Comment: @ferdy I stopped it after 10 hours..

Comment: I took the data here https://github.com/remykarem/apriori-rs/tree/master/benchmarks/data, around 500k+ then copy it 20x to another file to make 10M+. `csv to dataframe: 60s, groupby: 3s, apriori: 14s` for a total of `77s` I use `customer = orders.groupby("Invoice")["StockCode"].agg(tuple).tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you this approach to run this task parallel:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

length_of_input_file=len(raw_data_min)
total_offset_count=4  # number of parallel process to run
offset=int(length_of_input_file/total_offset_count // 1)
dataNew1=customer[0:offset-1]
dataNew2=customer[offset:2*offset-1]
dataNew3=customer[2*offset:3*offset-1]
dataNew4=customer[3*offset:4*offset-1]

def calculate_frequent_itemset(fractional_data):
    """Function that calculated the frequent dataset parallely"""
    itemsets, rules = apriori(fractional_data, min_support=MIN_SUPPORT, 
    min_confidence=MIN_CONFIDENCE)
    return itemsets, rules
        
p=Pool()
frequent_itemsets=p.map(calculate_frequent_itemset,(dataNew1,dataNew2,dataNew3,dataNew4))
p.close()
p.join()

itemsets1, rules1 =frequent_itemsets[0]
itemsets2, rules2=frequent_itemsets[1]
itemsets3, rules3=frequent_itemsets[2]
itemsets4, rules4=frequent_itemsets[3]
```

Comment: Great, elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: Be aware that this solution does not consider the priori among the splitted data, that is, the transactions in dataNew1 are not considered in the transactions in dataNew2 and other splitted datasets which then would result to an inaccurate and lesser association info.

Comment: @ferdy thanks for your input! You are right. Do you have any idea, how to improve my solution?

Comment: @vojtam I have a comment in your post with the benchmark data, could you try it?